# Intuitive demonstration of the formula giving the surface of a sphere.

Tags: geometry, spheres

I've been looking for a way to intuitively find the formula to calculate the surface of a sphere, so here is my process of thinking:

- In 2D: you imagine a segment of length R that rotates around an axis which corresponds to the center of the circle (Ω). The total angle formed by the revolution is 2π, so your formula is 2πR.
- In 3D: by analogy with 2D you imagine a circle on a plane, and you apply a similar rotation centered on Ω also directed by your radius of length R. And you get a sphere! The total angle formed by the revolution is π so by this logic the formula for the surface of the sphere you would get would be 2π²R²...

But when I searched on the net about the formula I found that it was 4πR², and all the demonstrations explaining the formula use integrals (which I only know how to use on a plane).

So I would like to know where I'm wrong in my reasoning and how to demonstrate (not rigorously) this formula using simple geometry tools and a bit of imagination.

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: You mean "use integrals"?

Comment: Yes thank you for noticing

Comment: Look up Archimedes' proof of the ratio between a sphere and its circumscribed cylinder (the ratio of surface area of the two, and the ratio of volume of the two are both $2:3$). There is bound to be someone on the internet who has written down how to do that without too much integration.

Comment: I'll definitely check that. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking, your circle calculation works because

$$ \mathrm{d}l = r \mathrm{d} \theta $$

so length accumulates at a constant rate proportional to angle. However, for the sphere,

$$ \mathrm{d}A = r^2 \cos(\varphi) \mathrm{d} \theta \mathrm{d} \varphi $$

(where I use $\theta$ for the angle around the $z$ axis, and $\varphi$ for the angle above the xy plane)

Roughly speaking, the two things going right are:

- $\theta$ and $\varphi$ vary in perpendicular directions, so an "area element" is simply the product of the two "length elements"
- $\varphi$ traces out lengths at a constant rate

but something also goes wrong:

- $\theta$ does not trace out length at a constant rate

In particular, at high latitudes, increasing $\theta$ traces out a small distance, but near the equator, increasing $\theta$ traces out a large distance.

Put differently, the East-West distance between longitude lines is much greater when you're near the equator than when you're near the poles.

(also, you made another mistake: you only need to rotate a circle through an angle of $\pi$ to obtain an entire sphere)

Comment: Your answer seems to enlighten what was wrong (and indeed it's a rotation of pi not 2pi), but how do get the formula you used to explain the variations of theta and phy?

Comment: @Gornemant: I looked up a reference for formulas in spherical coordinates. :)  If you're comfortable with  calculus of differential forms there's actually a nice calculation: since spheres are regions of constant $r$, $\mathrm{d}V = \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}A$. So if you convert $\mathrm{d}V = \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}z$ to polar coordinates, you can obtain the form of $\mathrm{d}A$. Otherwise, there's a standard (but, IMO, irritating) calculation estimating the area of an 'infinitesimal' area element over which $\theta$ and $\varphi$ vary a small amount, approximating it by a rectangle.

Comment: Can't see your formulas on my phone :) but yes I'm fine with differential. I'm also interested on the calculation of the area of an infinitesimal object, so if you have an article to share don't hesitate. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your analogy fails because different parts of the circumference of the circle you rotate are different distance from the rotation axis.  That means the area they sweep out is different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I understand better now

Answer (score 0):

To correct the example, instead of thinking of little circles, think of little [Lunes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalLune.html) which have area $2r^2\theta$.

[image: A lune]

Summing over the total $2\pi$, you get a total area of $4\pi r^2$.

The way to think about the area of a small spherical lune is:

- Imaging the top half, the width at the equator is $r \theta$
- The width at angle $\phi$ above the equator will be $r \theta cos(\phi)$.
- The total area of the top half will be $\int_{0}^{r\pi/2}r\theta cos(\frac{\phi}{r}) d\phi$ = $r \theta \big[r sin(\frac{\phi}{r}) \big]_{0}^{\frac{r \pi}{2}} $ = $r^2\theta$. That is, the area is the integral over the height of the half lune of the width of the half lune.

If you can imagine, I have peeled off a lune, and assumed it was small enough to be flattened, then it's area is twice this integral, $2r^2\theta$

This is disappointingly unintuitive, sorry, I'll think about removing the need for an integral.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be a good way of picturing the rotation, but how do you know that the radius of the small lune corresponds to : 2r²θ ?

Comment: I have added how you can calculate a small Lune area with an integral, but I can't find a way of thinking about triangles or anything for now.

Comment: It's fine, it's still interesting to see how integrals can be used in 3D. Thank you for your help I now understand better the relation between theta and phy